# How to create dynamic Timeout Handles in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript

### Question

I am using `setTimeout()` to implement *"user is typing"* messages for a chatroom. The timeout is stored in a handle so that the timeout can be cleared on sequential keypresses and reset so that the timeout truly represents when the user is done typing.

However, say there's a chatroom with chatters A, B and C. If A begins typing, then B begins typing, the timeout for A is cleared and will never disappear.

So, is there a way to dynamically create timeout handles so that I can only clear the appropriate handle regardless of how many users are in the chatroom or are currently typing?

### Code

**index.js**

```
io.on('connection', function(socket){

    socket.on('csTyping', function(user){
        socket.broadcast.emit('scTyping', user);
    });
});
```

**chat.js**

```
var typingLock = false;
var tMsgTimeout = 1 * 1000;
var tLockTimeoutHandle = window.setTimeout(() => {
    typingLock = false;
}, tMsgTimeout);
window.clearTimeout(tLockTimeoutHandle);

var tMsgTimeoutHandle = window.setTimeout(() => {
    removeTypingMsg(0);
}, tMsgTimeout);
window.clearTimeout(tMsgTimeoutHandle);

message.addEventListener('keypress', function(){
    if (!typingLock) {
        socket.emit('csTyping', clientUsername);
        typingLock = true;

        window.clearTimeout(tLockTimeoutHandle);
        tLockTimeoutHandle = window.setTimeout(() => {
            typingLock = false;
        }, tMsgTimeout);
    }
});

socket.on('scTyping', function(user){
    feedback.innerHTML += "<p id='typing" + user + "'><em>" + user + " is typing a message...</em></p>";

    window.clearTimeout(tMsgTimeoutHandle);
    tMsgTimeoutHandle = window.setTimeout(() => {
        removeTypingMsg('typing' + user);
    }, tMsgTimeout);
});
```

Comment: Create an object like `{ [clientUsername]: timeoutHandle }` and clear only the timeouts for the users that are done typing?

Comment: @HereticMonkey How would I access the value since [clientUsername] is a variable?

Comment: You access it via ```parentObject[clientUsername]``` [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/c3k6evrw/)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Store you timeout handles in an object, like so

```
var timeouts = {};
timeouts[clientUsername] = setTimeout(function(){}, 1000);
```

And then you can clear the timeouts with this:

```
clearTimeout(timeouts[clientUsername]);
```

Although, instead of using lots of timeouts, I would recommend a different approach:  Use a setInterval to regularly check a timestamp for when an event happened - if the timestamp is over 10 seconds old (or however old) then you can execute the code you want.

Comment: Worked perfectly. Just had to replace every occurrence of `clearTimeout()`, `timeoutHanlde = [...]` with your example.